# Fill a html form without submit, just open the browser with fields filled. In JAVA

Tags: java, html, forms, browser, htmlunit

I'm developing a JAVA SWING application, and when i click on a button, and I want it to open a browser page with the HTML form fields fully filled(with the data that I want to pass from JAVA application), understood?

In this moment i'm using HtmlUnit library, but if you know something better, I'm open to sugestions!

This is what i have:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://www.google.com");
HtmlForm form = page1.getFormByName("search");
HtmlButton button = form.getButtonByName("submitSearch");
HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByName("searchTxtField");
textField.setValueAttribute("TEST VALUE");
HtmlPage page2 = button.click(); //final line
```

On the final line I submit the form, instead of that, I want it to open a web browser with the  text:"TEXT VALUE" in "searchTxtField".

HELP ME, please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HtmlUnit doesn't control any external web browser. It **is** a web browser (without any graphical UI).

Use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) to control an external web browser.

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 6, you could use the method in [`public void browse(URI uri)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse%28java.net.URI%29) the [`java.awt.Desktop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html). You need build an URI with some parameters.

```
try {
    URI uri = new URI("http://www.google.com/#q=TEST+VALUE&oq=TEST+VALUE");
    Desktop desktop = null;
    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
    }
    if (desktop != null)
        desktop.browse(uri);
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    // log error
}
```

Check [Google Search URL Parameters – Query String Anatomy](http://www.blueglass.com/blog/google-search-url-parameters-query-string-anatomy/)

Comment: in case of google i can do that.. because they use method GET to fill the input text value. But in my case that is not possible. But, thanks.